# Fetching signed_request in a Facebook App with Ruby/Sinatra and the Rest-Graph gem

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, sinatra, facebook-iframe, facebook-page

I've built a Facebook app using Sinatra and the [Rest-Graph gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-graph). Now I would like to [embed the app as an iframe tab in a Facebook Page](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/).

To do that, I need to fetch data from the `signed_request` sent to my app by Facebook.

The Rest-Graph gem states the following feature [on its Github page](https://github.com/cardinalblue/rest-graph):

> Utility to extract access_token and
>   check sig in cookies/signed_request

I couldn't find any documentation on how to use this "utility". Can you point me to some documentation or even better, give me an example on how this is used with Ruby/Sinatra?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nearly all of the Graph API libraries that are available deal with signed_request in a similar way. Rest-Graph has a parse_signed_request method ([Rest-Graph/lib/core.rb](https://github.com/godfat/rest-graph/blob/master/lib/rest-graph/core.rb#L364)) that you can call in Sinatra.

I'm using Koala for this with Sinatra, and it works as advertised:

```
oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(APP_ID, APP_CODE)
signed_request = oauth.parse_signed_request(params["signed_request"])
```

You get back a hash of the JSON object that Facebook posts:

```
{
"algorithm"=>"HMAC-SHA256",
"issued_at"=>1303883452, 
"user"=> 
{
"country"=>"us",
"locale"=>"en_US"
},
"user_id"=>"100002364226618"
}
```

rest-graph makes it pretty easy, too. Just tested this in a Sinatra app. Works perfectly:

```
rg = RestGraph.new( :app_id => APP_ID, :secret => APP_SECRET)
parsed_request = rg.parse_signed_request!(params["signed_request"])
```

Lemme know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Just saw that you edited your code. It now reflects the solution I got from cardinalblue today. Anyway, as you were the first answering my question and I can't take that bounty back: It's yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just got a [response to this question from "cardinalblue"](https://github.com/cardinalblue/rest-graph/blob/d392fbaf2d63a858a55fe656d6a993c7e289187c/example/sinatra/config.ru), the developer of the Rest-Graph gem. This little example was exactly what I was looking for:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rest-graph'

app_id = '123'
secret = 'abc'
config = {:app_id => app_id,
          :secret => secret}

post '/' do
  rg = RestGraph.new(config)
  rg.parse_signed_request!(params['signed_request'])
  "#{rg.get('me').inspect.gsub('<', '&lt;')}\n"
end

run Sinatra::Application
```

Sidenote: In case you're building something similar, please note the `post '/' do`. Facebook Pages fetch your page [using a POST request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/canvas/post/) instead of a GET.

Comment: Yep -- I'm using a POST in my app; guess I assumed that anyone looking to parse signed_request would be doing the same. :) Cheers!

Comment: I guess you're right. I just added that line, because it took me some time to get that, as my app wasn't running inside FB canvas before (that's also why I was looking for this "signed_request" thing ;-)).

Comment: FWIW, Facebook also uses signed_request the deauthorize URL. Just something you'll probably want to implement now that you're parsing it successfully.